# How to bind parameter with Boost asio io_context post?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind, boost-beast

I am trying to post data to io_context, if I bind post with newdata method (with no parameter) it get called, however if I pass any parameter it failed to call newdata method.

```
std::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_context >ioc = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_context>();
 :
ioc->post(boost::bind(&myclass::newdata, this));  /// <-- this get called
ioc->post(boost::bind(&myclass::newdata, this, 1));  /// <-- this get failed, no compile time error
```

// I tried with boost::function, but it failed to compile

```
boost::function<void(int>)> p(boost::bind(&myclass::newdata, this, _1));
ioc->post(p(1));   // <-- compile time error
```

Comment: Nothing specific to boost and asio, use modern C++ lambda function instead of old bind

Comment: @JeanDavy I tried with lambda, however I observed it too failed few times, not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: So focus on what is going wrong, the problem is not lambda itself.

Comment: I found that post is successfully working, however handler never getting executed. somehow ioc not executing handlers...looking into it more.

Answer (score 0):

The thread which is calling ioc->post() doesn't have ioc->run(), as soon I put the same it worked.